# Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'factory'), ILoggerFactory in ASP.NET Core MVC, .NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, hangfire, .net-5

An error is coming up about ILoggerFactory injection when using Hangfire for a recurring job.

This is the Program.cs file:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = BuildWebHost(args);
        host.Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

This is the controller calling the Hangfire recurring job:

```
using Hangfire;

public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<AdminController> _logger;

    public AdminController(ILogger<AdminController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Helper.SendMessages(), "*/10 * * * *");

        return View();
    }
}
```

There isn't any line of code in Startup.cs about logging. I'm using the default settings.

The following error is shown when the program runs:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Recurring job can't be scheduled, see inner exception for details.
 ---> Hangfire.Common.JobLoadException: Could not load the job. See inner exception for the details.
 ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'factory')
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger`1..ctor(ILoggerFactory factory)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object[] )
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObjectUsingCreatorWithParameters(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, ObjectConstructor`1 creator, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract objectContract, JsonProperty containerMember, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id, Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultCreator)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ResolvePropertyAndCreatorValues(JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObjectUsingCreatorWithParameters(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, ObjectConstructor`1 creator, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract objectContract, JsonProperty containerMember, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id, Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultCreator)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Hangfire.Common.SerializationHelper.Deserialize(String value, Type type, SerializationOption option)
   at Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.DeserializeArgument(String argument, Type type)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.DeserializeArgument(String argument, Type type)
   at Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.DeserializeArguments(MethodInfo methodInfo, String[] arguments)
   at Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.DeserializeJob()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.DeserializeJob()
   at Hangfire.RecurringJobEntity..ctor(String recurringJobId, IDictionary`2 recurringJob, ITimeZoneResolver timeZoneResolver, DateTime now)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Hangfire.Server.RecurringJobScheduler.ScheduleRecurringJob(BackgroundProcessContext context, IStorageConnection connection, String recurringJobId, RecurringJobEntity recurringJob, DateTime now)
```

Here's the detail of the page:
[image: ILoggerFactory Debugging Details]

How can I inject ILoggerFactory in .NET 5, and fix this problem, please.

Thank you.

Comment: Is Helper a static class?

Comment: Yes, It's a static class.

Comment: Did you make necessary changes in Startup.cs to configure Hangfire?

Comment: Can you share relevant code of Helper.SendMessages() ?

Comment: The necessary changes in Startup.cs is what I need. By default ILogger is available out of the box. But I don't know how to implement ILoggerFactory dependency injection required for Hangfire. The error message shows this issue.

Comment: The Helper.SenderMessage is just a call of an api for sending a SMS. No logging, no nothing.